# Create Mac apps with Xamarin from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xamarin, xamarin.mac

It seems to be easy enough to create Android and IOS apps on Xamarin in Visual Studio, but I can't see how to create OSX apps.

On the Xamarin download page for Windows/VS it states that this "Includes the following: Mac - Develop Apps with Xamarin.Mac". There is no option to create an OSX/Mac project

Apologies if I'm being dense but I am going round in circles here and always end up with information on creating IOS apps. I know I can create apps using Xamarin Studio on the Mac but that isn't ideal.

Comment: [Question on Xamarin Mac Forum](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/3252/is-mac-osx-builds-enabled-via-visual-studio) - I asked the same question on the Xamarin Mac forum and it seems that you currently cannot build for Mac from Visual Studio. You're stuck with using Xamarin Studio. There were some alternative's but nothing official and not having resharper for it is pretty lame

Comment: Thanks, It's all very frustrating and quite misleading. I'm quite experienced with OSX, but it is still comparably weak as a development environment. Xamarin studio is also a giant step backwards, particularly for debugging.

Comment: Does anyone know if this situation has changed? It says on Xamarin home page Windows, iOS and Android from Visual Studio so it would seem not?

Comment: This is especially obnoxious when there are Xamarin Studio bugs where the work around left by Xamarin is "do it in Visual Studio"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wasn't possible before, but it is possible now with Xamarin for Visual Studio 4.2. The support is limited to certain project types though. More information is available in the [blog post](https://blog.xamarin.com/major-updates-ios-10-android-nougat-and-other-tasty-bits/).

Comment: Thanks - the [release notes are here](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs/xamarin.vs_4/xamarin.vs_4.2/#Xamarin.Mac_minimum_support.). I'm still trying to see the main benefit here - ability to view the code in VS? I hope it gets full support for building applications one day.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't benefit me, but hopefully this is just the start of something like the IOS build process (where the build occurs on a networked mac)